# PHPmyadmin Access denied in bluehost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, shared-hosting

I have hosted my joomla website with Bluehost, and started developing the database. Every time I access PHPmyadmin through bluehost, and start adding tables, it prevents from doing it saying access denied. I have logged in with database super user.
As I checked with Bluehost support,  they say no issues in their end. 
Also I tried with another browser,  and another network as well. Seems to be helpless.
Can someone please assist me with this issue. Last few days have been terrible with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer this question because you haven't shared what you have already tried and I may be wasting my time.

Your MySQL credentials may be out of synch with your cPanel credentials.

The easiest way to fix this is to reset your cPanel password.

**Tip:** only use alphanumeric characters as phpMyAdmin may be struggling with special characters in the password and this may be the reason the passwords are out of synch.

You will probably need to log out and log back in again before you can access phpMyAdmin.